# set specific value for some joined data

Tags: mysql, database, join

i would like to add a col in order to mark users that they are coming from view_all_involved_users.scientist_id as `scientist` while other users as `others`

```
VIEW `view_all_involved_users2` AS

SELECT DISTINCT
    `tbl_user`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,
    `tbl_user`.`name` AS `name`,
    `view_all_involved_users`.`flagship_activity_id` AS `flagship_activity_id`
FROM
    (`tbl_user`
    LEFT JOIN `view_all_involved_users` ON (((`view_all_involved_users`.`flagship_leader` = `tbl_user`.`user_id`)
        OR (`view_all_involved_users`.`flagship_activity_focalpoint_id` = `tbl_user`.`user_id`)
        OR (`view_all_involved_users`.`flagship_activity_coleader_id` = `tbl_user`.`user_id`)
        OR (`view_all_involved_users`.`output_leader_id` = `tbl_user`.`user_id`)
        OR (`view_all_involved_users`.`output_coleader_id` = `tbl_user`.`user_id`)
        OR (`view_all_involved_users`.`scientist_id` = `tbl_user`.`user_id`)
        OR (`view_all_involved_users`.`clustuer_coordinator_id` = `tbl_user`.`user_id`)
        OR (`view_all_involved_users`.`scientist_id` = `tbl_user`.`user_id`)
        OR (`view_all_involved_users`.`clustuer_cocoordinator_id` = `tbl_user`.`user_id`))))
```

Comment: your question is  not clear to me please explain better .. eventually add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge done

Comment: Your question is still unclear.

Comment: @Shadow view_all_involved_users contains various users such scientists leaders etc  ,both tables  (view_all_involved_users and users ) has a common users relation.

Comment: @Shadow i would like to mark every contact shown as either contact or ~scientist~ upon ~user~ type

Comment: case statement?

Comment: exactly, you solved my problem please add your comment as an answer to vote you @P.Salmon

Comment: (CASE
            WHEN ISNULL(`tbl_flagship_activity_result_scientists`.`user_id`) THEN 'contact'
            ELSE 'scientist'
        END) AS `type`

Comment: Still struggling? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(CASE WHEN ISNULL(tbl_flagship_activity_result_scientists.user_id) THEN 'contact' ELSE 'scientist' END) AS type
```